Produce 3 columns: one patient subject, date of 1st event, date of 2nd event
Working with a patient visits during a trial. THey're scheduled to come in at specific instances, visit ID- Safety Visit Cycle 01 Day01... cycle 2 day 01.. and so on. I also have a study group assignment table.
I want to create a table to merge specific information from:

CohortInfo (Key is SubjectID)
DateOfVisit (Each row is unique to SubjectID and InstanceID)

This ihe final table I would like:
| SubjectID |Cohort Assignment| C1D1VIsitDate    | C1D4VISITDate    |
|    1000001|Cohort A         | 01Jan01          | 04Jan01          |
I was able to reorg the DateOfVIsit chart to create a table with subject ID, C1D1. I still need to add another column, Date of C1D4 for each subject ID- I'm stuck here!
AFter I create this table, I would use the JOIN function to add cohort info..
SELECT
Subject,
(select FIeld3Value
FROM myproject.patients.DateOfVisit
WHERE InstanceName = 'Safety Visit Cycle 01 Day 01') as C1D1VisitDate,
(select FIeld3Value
FROM myproject.patients.DateOfVisit
WHERE InstanceName = 'Safety Visit Cycle 01 Day 04') as C1D4VisitDate,
From myproject.patients.DateOfVisit
ORDER BY Subject DESC;
I was expecting to create
| SubjectID | C1D1VIsitDate    | C1D4VISITDate    |
|    1000001| 01Jan01          | 04Jan01          |

You seem to want some kind of pivoting logic here, perhaps:
SELECT
    Subject,
    MAX(CASE WHEN InstanceName = 'Safety Visit Cycle 01 Day 01'
             THEN FIeld3Value END) AS C1D1VisitDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN InstanceName = 'Safety Visit Cycle 01 Day 04'
             THEN FIeld3Value END) AS C1D4VisitDate
FROM myproject.patients.DateOfVisit
GROUP BY Subject
ORDER BY Subject DESC;

